# Is there a function for selecting multiple data/row ranges in python?

Tags: python

My excel data has 600 rows. I am creating an LSTM model. I want to preprocess my data by getting rid of weekends (I did that already), holidays and summer break (needs to be done).

I want to select the following ranges: [0:50], [60:300] and [452:550].

I tried `iloc` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need first to convert your ranges to slices and put them in a list, then you call `pandas.concat()` and use a generator that slices your dataframe based on the list of slices you created:

```
ranges = [slice(0,50), slice(60,300), slice(452,550)]

filtered_df = pd.concat(df.iloc[x, :] for x in ranges)
```